# create an onClick event on an inflated layout

Tags: java, android

I have a GeoPoint whenever its clicked an inflated layout appears with details on that GeoPoint. Initally I had a button within the inflated layout but now I have discovered that:

The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. so is it possible to create an onclick event for the entire inflated layout. Below shows the xml file for the inflated layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:minWidth="150dp"
android:id="@+id/placeInfo"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:textColor="#ff555555"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtHours"
    android:textColor="#ff555555"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtCountry"
    android:textColor="#ff555555"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
    android:textColor="#ff555555"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtPostCode"
    android:textColor="#ff555555"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now found the solution to this problem, as you can't select a specific element within an inflated layout you have to select the full inflated layout. This is done through the following line of code

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() { 
   @Override 
   public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) { 

   }
});
```